# Adding a DIV wrapper to a custom search form in Drupal7 - It's added but not rendered

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm having issues trying to alter how my form is rendered. However, I've tried to keep it as simple as the tutorial's I've found has kept it - but even though my $form item in the template.php's hrfrontpage_form_alter function has the added div wrapper - it won't render it. How come?

In my Module:

```
    function rsearch_block_info()
    {
            $blocks['rsearch_form'] = array(
                    'info' => t('Search Recruiters Front'),
            );

            return $blocks;
    }

    function rsearch_block_view($delta = '')
    {
            $block = array();

            switch($delta)  {
                    case 'rsearch_form' :
                            $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('rsearch_front');
                            break;
            }

            return $block;
    }
```

In my template.php:

```
function hrfrontpage_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        switch($form_id) {
                case 'rsearch_front' :
                        $form['divstart'] = array(
                                '#value' => '<div style="background-color:green;">',
                                '#weight' => -5
                        );
                        $form['divend'] = array(
                                '#value' => '</div>',
                                '#weight' => 5
                        );
                        break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all you can't open a div in one form element and then close it in another one because each form element is wrapped in a div by default.

What you need to do is use the `'#prefix' and '#suffix'` field elements.

If you are trying to put a div wrapper around multiple fields then you need to put those fields inside a fieldset and use the prefix and suffix elements on the fieldset.

Simple case:

```
 $form['my_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'search',
    '#prefix' => '<div style="background-color:green;">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
 );
```

Complex case:

```
 unset($form['my_element']);

 $form['my_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div style="background-color:green;">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
 );
 $form['my_wrapper']['my_field'] = array(  //Make sure your fields are children of the wrapper element!
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'search',
 );
 $form['my_wrapper']['my_submit'] = array(  //Make sure your fields are children of the wrapper element!
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'submit',
 );
```

Check out the form API:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7